# How to use the result of tf.argmax to access values at the corresponding positions?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to access values of a tensor next to their maximal values. For that, I get the locations of the maxima via `tf.argmax`, add one to it and then need to look up the values.

```
f0_binned = tf.random.normal([2, 1000, 360]) 
idx = tf.argmax(f0_binned, axis=-1) # [2, 1000]
tf.gather(f0_binned, idx+1, axis=-1).shape
# TensorShape([2, 1000, 2, 1000])
```

I would like to get something of the same shape as `idx`, but filled with the values of the corresponding positions. I only found `tf.gather`, but I am not sure if it is the correct operation and I am using it wrong or if I need to use an entirely different operation. Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: what about using numpy?

Comment: I cannot use numpy since I need the gradients (not through the argmax, but the gradients of the values wrt some previous operations). But if you know how to do it in numpy that would maybe also help, maybe I can translate that to tensorflow code.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the gradients using TF and then use NumPy to find the values you are looking for:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

f0_binned = tf.random.normal([2, 1000, 360])
idx = np.argmax(f0_binned, axis=-1)
i, j, k = f0_binned.numpy().shape
I, J = np.ogrid[:i, :j]
idx_plus_one = idx + 1
idx_plus_one[np.where(idx_plus_one >= k)] = k - 1
the_values = f0_binned.numpy()[I, J, idx_plus_one]
```

Also when you doing `idx + 1` you should check it is not getting out of bound (for 3rd dimension).